# Why are my Cooley-Tukey and Brute Force (Fourier) algorithms giving very different results?

Tags: c++, algorithm, fft, complex-numbers

I finished writing my fourier alogorithm code.  It implements the cooley-tukey and brute force (Fourier Transform) methods onto a text file with one column for time (index) and the other for temperature in kelvin (value).  My code takes in a txt file, then does either brute-force or cooley-tukey, and lastly outputs it as txt file.  Brute Force is coming out with only real numbers, and Cooley-Tukey is outputting both real and imaginary.

I'm also not familiar with Physics at all...I'm thinking it is a flaw in the math:

Brute Force Algorithm (.cpp file):

```
      void Brute_force<T>::DFT(std::vector<double>* index,
        std::vector<double>* value, 
        std::vector<complex<double>> &result)
      {

      // For each output element
      for (size_t freq = 0; freq < index->size(); freq += 
      this->frequency_step)
      {
        complex<double> sum(0.0, 0.0);
        // For each input element
        for (size_t time = 0; time < index->size(); time++)
        {
          double angle = 2 * M_PI * time * freq / index- 
          >size();
          sum = sum + index->at(time) * exp(-angle);
        }
        result.push_back(sum);
      }
    }

    template class Brute_force<double>;
```

Cooley-Tukey Algorithm (.cpp file):

```
            void Cooley_tukey<T>::FFT(std::vector<T>* index, std::vector<T>* value, std::vector<complex<T>>& result)
            {
                std::cout << index->size() << std::endl;
                // Make copy of array and apply window
                for (unsigned int time = 0; time < index->size(); time++)
                {
                    result.push_back(index->at(time));
                    std::cout << result.at(time) << std::endl;
                    //temp.at(time) *= 1; // Window
                }

                // Start recursion function to split up the tasks
                FFT_REC(result, index->size());
            }


            template<typename T>
            void Cooley_tukey<T>::FFT_REC(std::vector<complex<T>>& result, int total_time)
            {
                // Check if it is split up enough
                if (total_time >= 2)
                {

                    // Split even and odds up
            std::vector<complex<T>> odd;
            std::vector<complex<T>> even;
            odd.reserve(total_time/2);
            even.reserve(total_time/2);
            for (int i = 0; i < total_time / 2; i++)
            {
                even.push_back(result.at(i*2));
                odd.push_back(result.at(i*2+1));
            }


                    // DFT portion of FFT - calculates after everything has been split up through FFT_REC
                    for (int frequency = 0; frequency < total_time / 2; frequency += this->frequency_step)
                    {
                        std::complex<T> t = exp(std::complex<T>(0, -2 * M_PI * frequency / total_time)) * odd.at(frequency);

                        //Result of Cooley-Tukey algorithm:
                            //*This gives us the frequency values at certain times
                        result.at(frequency) = even.at(frequency) + t;
                        result.at(total_time / 2 + frequency) = even.at(frequency) - t;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Brute-Force Results (txt file)(only part of it):

```
    6.003e+06 0
    736788 0
    344823 0
    224583 0
    166575 0
    132447 0
    109977 0
    94064.6 0
    82206.1 0
    73027.7 0
    65713.2 0
    59747.3 0
```

Cooley-Tukey Results (txt file)(only part of it):

```
      4001 0
      4004.99 -6.28946
      4008.96 -12.5914
      4012.91 -18.9058
      4016.84 -25.2326
      4020.75 -31.5716
      4024.64 -37.9229
      4028.51 -44.2865
      4032.36 -50.6621
      4036.19 -57.0498
      4040 -63.4494
```

Comment: Take any software that does Discrete Fourier transforms, and put your data through it. Then you will know if either of your implementations is correct or not. You will then be able to ask for help debugging one algorithm, rather than two.

Answer (score 2):

A real-valued result is highly suspicious. So I took a quick look at that code.

You are missing an *i* in your exponent. You compute the exponent of a real value, leading to a real value. You need to use

```
std::exp(std::complex<double>{0,-angle})
```

I have not looked at the rest of the code. As I said in a comment, you should compare your results to those of existing tools that you know are correct (MATLAB, Python/NumPy, etc), to narrow down the problem statement.